# Entering the Netherlands with a Croatian residence permit expiring in 1,5 months

Tags: air-travel, netherlands, croatia, permits, entry-permit

I am a Turkish citizen and I have a valid residence permit from Croatia expiring on November 22nd. And my flight ticket to the Netherlands is on October 7th. I will be flying from Istanbul, so I was just confused if I am eligible to enter Netherlands with this Croatian residence permit. Or do I need a Schengen visa? Just to make it clear, I am going to the Netherlands to apply residence permit there since my Croatian husband is already living and working in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter as long as your residence permit is valid:

> ## Which visa do I need to travel to the Netherlands?
>
> ...
>
> ### Valid residence permit issued by another Schengen country
>
> If you already have a valid residence permit for another Schengen country, you do not need a visa for the Netherlands for up to 90 days.

Source: https://www.government.nl/topics/holidays-and-travels/question-and-answer/which-visa-do-i-need-to-travel-to-the-netherlands

(In fact, you have a right to enter under the free movement directive.   Since you have the valid residence permit there's no need to go into that, but it deserves mention.)